# How to make my script that has a timer to shutdown my machine work?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, 22.04, shutdown

I have script to shutdown my computer after 2 minutes, and 1 minute before shutdown it sends a notification that says *"It will shutdown after 1 minute"*. The script will be executed on click via a launcher, and the launcher will appear among other applications.

So I created the script with a `.sh` extension and an icon for the launcher.

Then I created a launcher with a `.desktop` extension in `./local/share/applications/` directory and put it there as `shutdown_script.desktop`.

It's appearing among other applications and sending notification, but PC is not shutting down. I checked the directory address of the script and all is correct. I also asked  ChatGPT, but it's not helping.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the time for shutdown (in 1 hour)
shutdown_time=$(date -d '+2 minutes' +%H:%M)

# Set the time for notification (1 minute before shutdown)
notification_time=$(date -d '+1 minutes' +%H:%M)

# Display a notification 1 minute before shutdown
notify-send "Shutdown Notification" "Your computer will shut down in 1 minute at $shutdown_time" -t 60000

# Schedule the shutdown
echo "shutdown -h now" | at $shutdown_time

echo "Shutdown scheduled at $shutdown_time. Notification will be displayed at $notification_time."
```

And here is the `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shutdown timer Script
Exec="/home/engineer/Programming/Projects/Ubuntu - Automatic shutdown script/shutdown_script.sh"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon="/home/engineer/Programming/Projects/Ubuntu - Automatic shutdown script/icon.png"
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: Is the `at` command installed on your system? And why don't you use the `shutdown -h +2` command instead of `at`. And, never trust any AI tool; currently their answers are 50% correct at most!

Answer (score 1):

I tested your script and it worked for shutting down my system. However, I initially encountered an error:

```
Can't open /run/atd.pid to signal atd. No atd running?
```

So it looks like that on my system (Fedora 39, not Ubuntu, so I'm not sure if that's the case for your system as well) `atd` (`at` daemon) was not running and I had to start it manually and also enable it with the following commands:

```
systemctl start atd
systemctl enable atd
```

After that, the script ran normally and shut my computer down successfully.

Another thing I noticed is that, due to the way you wrote your script, the notification is shown immediately, not 1 minute before shutting down the system. So some modifications to your script are needed. If I were you, I wouldn't use `at` at all for this task and I would proceed with using [`sleep`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/sleep.1.html) instead.

So the script would look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set the time for shutdown (in 1 hour)
shutdown_time=$(date -d '+2 minutes' +%H:%M:%S)

# Set the time for notification (1 minute before shutdown)
notification_time=$(date -d '+1 minutes' +%H:%M:%S)

echo "Shutdown scheduled at $shutdown_time. Notification will be displayed at $notification_time."

# wait for the specified time (here 1 minute) - see `man sleep` for details
sleep 1m

# Display a notification 1 minute before shutdown
notify-send "Shutdown Notification" "Your computer will shut down in 1 minute at $shutdown_time" -t 60000

sleep 1m

echo "shutdown -h now"
```

I have also added `:%S` to your `date` commands so you can see if the notification is shown at the correct time. If it is (which should), you may remove it.

I have also put `shutdown -h now` inside `echo`, so you can first test that it is displayed at the correct time (which should). If it works, remove the `echo` to actually shut down the system when the script is run.

Also note that if you use GNOME as your desktop environment, `-t 60000` will have no effect in `notify-send`. From [`man notify-send`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/notify-send.1.html):

> ```
>     -t, --expire-time=TIME
>            The duration, in milliseconds, for the notification to appear on screen.
>
>     (Ubuntu's Notify OSD and GNOME Shell both ignore this parameter.)
> ```

Finally, since it seems (from your comments in the script) that you created this script to shut your system down after 1 hour, for the final form of your script you should take into account the 1 minute `sleep` after showing the notification. So for shutting the system down after 1 hour, you should set the first `sleep` to `59m` and adjust `shutdown_time` and `notification_time` accordingly.

With all these, this how your final script should be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Set the time for shutdown (in 1 hour)
shutdown_time=$(date -d '+60 minutes' +%H:%M:%S)

# Set the time for notification (1 minute before shutdown)
notification_time=$(date -d '+59 minutes' +%H:%M:%S)

echo "Shutdown scheduled at $shutdown_time. Notification will be displayed at $notification_time."

# wait for the specified time (here 59 minutes) - see `man sleep` for details
sleep 59m

# Display a notification 1 minute before shutdown
notify-send "Shutdown Notification" "Your computer will shut down in 1 minute at $shutdown_time" -t 60000

sleep 1m

shutdown -h now
```